# Estimating size of parts in boxes

Tags: linear-algebra, combinations, linear-programming, word-problem

I have a problem where I need to estimate the size of parts, without knowing the size of any parts.  I do however know the size of the boxes that combinations of the parts are in.  The parts however, may not fully utilize the space in the box.

For example:

Box 1 (Large) holds 10 of A, 3 of B, and 1 of C
Box 2 (Large) holds 4 of C, 6 of D, and 7 of E
Box 3 (Large) holds 5 of A
Box 4 (Small) holds 10 of D

Now, from this data I need to know the max size each of the parts could be.

My intuition pointed me towards linear programming with the following set of constraints:

10A + 3B + C <= 1
4C + 6D + 7E <= 1
5A <= 1
10D <= .1

Then maximizing the objective function of A+B+C+D+E.  I used excel's solver to run the LP Simplex, but the results did not seem to make much since.. It was giving me several 0s for the variable values which is definitely not what I am after.

Any help would be appreciated on this, preferably on theory or direction.  I am not looking for a solution to the problem since this is just an example of my dataset.  My dataset is actually vastly underdetermined (~40,000 parts and ~15,000 boxes). My second guess would be to look into Linear Algebra, maybe some sort of regression but I figured I'd post the question while I look through other options.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to find the maximum possible value of? Finding the maximum possible size of A, and the maximum possible size of B, … is very different from finding the maximum possible value of A+B+C+D+E.

Comment: @Casper The end goal is to estimate the space utilization of each box, to predict which boxes may have extra space to hold more parts. I was approaching this by estimating the max size of each part.

Comment: Finding the max size of A is very simple: assume that B, C, D, and E have size 0 (or whatever the minimal size is). That makes it trivial. Then you do the same for each of B, C, D, and E. But I don't think that is what you want. You probably want to maximize some value that combines the sizes in *some* way - but I'm not sure A+B+C+D+E is what you are after either. Maybe you want the minimal possible value of (1-10A-3B-C)+(1-4C-6D-7E)+(1-5A)+(.1-10D)?

Comment: The high quantity parts are dominating my objective function and forcing the others to 0.  I'll have to think of some metrics to score each method before I move forward.